# c#(.net) run shell script on windows by cygwin

Tags: c#, windows, cygwin

I have some shell scripts (bash) work correctly on mac. But i want to run them on windows in C#. I think cygwin can make this. but i don't know how to write the code. is there anybody can help me?

Comment: Hope I understood your question correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string

Comment: @Jannik Thanks, let's say i have a command line:"./foo.sh -c black." how to run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Process class to use CYGWIN under C#.

There are other questions dealing with CYGWIN. Look at this question:
[bash pipes - I am trying to call script from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586424/bash-pipes-i-am-trying-to-call-script-from-c-sharp)

Comment: i can run it in c# now. but some of the commands can't been found. such as type/dirname/grep. how to set the command's path to make the scripts run correctly?

Comment: The question I linked you in the answer above deals with that question. It seems like you have to have to set the path inside your script :)

Comment: Thanks Jannik, i made it as your comments.